# How to get number of rows from NpgsqlDataReader

Tags: c#, npgsql

I am trying to get the number of rows from the NpgsqlDataReader after using a select statement. The reason I am trying to check is to see if it has any data, a single row, or if it has multiple rows before working with the data. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is being done in C# .NET 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a bit of googling the NpgsqlDataReader would seem to be very similar to the [sqldatareader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx). The sqldatareader does not have a built in way to get the row count. [It would appear](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/6ba51f35-5f09-4180-88e2-48d8d4de93de/) you would have to loop through and perform your own count if you wanted to get the rowcount.

Answer (score 2):

If the `NpgsqlDataReader` inherits from `DbDataReader` as other DataReaders do, you can check with

```
if (reader.HasRows) {...}
```

if there are any results. But I don't think that you can get the actual number of rows without looping through the reader....

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a quick preview.

1.) does not have a result
2.) does have one result
3.) does have multiple results

you could execute the similar SQL Statement with a LIMITer. This should be very fast. And after that execution, you are going to retrieve the complete data.

example:

select * from [TABLE] where [CONDITION] LIMIT 2

if you get 0 rows, no result / 
if you get 1 row, one result /
if you get 2 rows, multiple results

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to get the number of rows for progress bar, but it seems I can't iterating twice is too much work for just showing progress ;)

You can create a proxy class, which is a child of `NpgsqlDataReader` and where you re-implement iterator (extends `IEnumerable`), which will implicitly iterate over first up to 2 rows if you either `.Read()` or ask `.CountClass` - then it will give those 2 from it's cache before directly reading the rest.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case, but in mine I put the results of the query into a List, then I can count the items on the list, it might not apply to your use case, but you can do a bunch of stuff on the results once you have it on a list.